# Who should I address and what format should I keep for letters in a PhD application?

Tags: application-cover-letter

I am trying to apply to some PhD programs and I have some questions regarding the required letters.

First, I looked for many differences between a cover letter and a motivation letter as such a cover letter is asked mostly by a company than a University and a motivation letter is vice versa, so, when a university asks for a cover letter which format I should keep when writing? For example, as explained in most online sources, a cover letter should explain your CV and experiences while a motivation should your motivation as it is clear from the name. So, when writing a cover letter for a university can I also talk about my motivation? if not, then how can I show it?

Second, I am applying for a PhD position that on the advertisement it is mentioned to send my application to an email with a recipient name (who I found to be the scientific coordinator) while the leader of the project is also mentioned for inquiries. The question is that, should I address my cover letter to the leader or to the person receiving my email?

thanks...

Comment: This depends on place. In the US, it is a committee that makes decisions. Elsewhere (or in some fields) individual professors actually "hire" doctoral students.